# pdf zero size elements visible using ggsave

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I have an issue where fill colours from elements which are not present are appearing at the top of stacked barplots when saved as a pdf. These elements do not appear in the plot window in R or when saved as a png.

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(prop.table(xtabs(~class+cyl,mpg),1))
qplot(class,Freq,data=dat,geom="bar",fill=relevel(cyl,4))+scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")
ggsave("test.pdf")
```

A thin dark-blue line appear at the top of the "2seater" column which seems to remain the same thickness on the screen no matter how much you zoom in. I assume this is a pdf error rather than a ggplot2 error, but is there any way to avoid this?

**Edit**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.8.9 proto_0.3-9.2 reshape_0.8.4 plyr_1.6     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.5.0       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 tools_2.12.2
```

Comment: You should probably specify some info on your OS, R version, etc, since I can't reproduce this (OS X, R 2.14.0).

Comment: @joran Thanks, added sessionInfo

Comment: FWIW, I get the problem, and I'm running on Windows, with R 2.14.1. Not sure, though, whether it's a problem with the `pdf` device, or with the viewer.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Weird. Possibly a windows pdf device issue?

Comment: @joran -- To find out, we'd have to swap the pdfs drawn on our two machines. If you're interested, you can send it to the email address listed in my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be due to the `class*cylynder` combos that have zero frequencies, like the first line in the data frame shown here:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(prop.table(xtabs(~class+cyl,mpg),1))
head(dat, 3)
#     class cyl      Freq
# 1 2seater   4 0.0000000
# 2 compact   4 0.6808511
# 3 midsize   4 0.3902439
```

If you remove rows with `Freq==0`, and then plot, the problematic line goes away:

```
dat2 <- subset(dat, Freq>0)
qplot(class, Freq, data=dat2, geom="bar", fill=relevel(cyl,4)) +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")
ggsave("test.pdf")
```

Comment: On the bright side, I guess we now both know what a line of zero width looks like! Not many people have actually seen that.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (on Linux): zero values in histograms are displayed as thin black line in pdf viewers.

I could partly resolve it by saving using `cairo_pdf()` instead of `pdf()`.

In display with Sumatra or Evince it doesn't show up anymore, yet in PDF X-change Viewer it still does. This works also for your example code.

Edit: using the tikzDevice solves the problem in all viewers. One can then still create the pdf with pdflatex etc.